# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4223-BKEOR'

Tags: python, data-science

```
directory = "path/to/directory"
filename = "C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\TelcomCustomer-Churn_2.csv"
full_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

def load_csv(path='C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\TelcomCustomer-Churn_2.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\TelcomCustomer-Churn_2.csv')
    return df

def preprocess_data(df):
    df['TotalCharges'] = df['TotalCharges'].replace(" ", 0).astype('float')
​
    # Identify numeric and categorical columns
    numeric_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()
    categorical_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()
​
    # Fill in missing numeric values with the mean of the column
    for col in numeric_cols:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mean(), inplace=True)
​
    # Fill in missing categorical values with the mode of the column
    for col in categorical_cols:
        df[col].fillna(df[col].mode()[0], inplace=True)
​
    # Drop duplicates
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
​
    # One-hot encode categorical features
    X_cat = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorical_cols)
​
    X = X_cat.drop(columns='Churn_Yes', axis=1)
    y = X_cat['Churn_Yes']
    return X, y

def Split_data(X, y):
    
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    
    # Scale the features
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_scaled, X_test_scaled, y_train, y_test
)
print(Split_data(X, y))
```

the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_592\3782283586.py in <module>
----> 1 print(Split_data(X, y))

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_592\18160545.py in Split_data(X, y)
      5     # Scale the features
      6     scaler = StandardScaler()
----> 7     X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
      8     X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
      9     return X_train_scaled, X_test_scaled, y_train, y_test

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    850         if y is None:
    851             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 852             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    853         else:
    854             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    804         # Reset internal state before fitting
    805         self._reset()
--> 806         return self.partial_fit(X, y, sample_weight)
    807 
    808     def partial_fit(self, X, y=None, sample_weight=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py in partial_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    839         """
    840         first_call = not hasattr(self, "n_samples_seen_")
--> 841         X = self._validate_data(
    842             X,
    843             accept_sparse=("csr", "csc"),

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    564             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    565         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 566             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    567             out = X
    568         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    744                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    745                 else:
--> 746                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    747             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    748                 raise ValueError(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   2062 
   2063     def __array__(self, dtype: npt.DTypeLike | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 2064         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   2065 
   2066     def __array_wrap__(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '4223-BKEOR'
```

I did not understand where i have done the mistake in the above code

Answer (score 0):

The error happend because one of the data in your X_train contains non numeric value.

Try the below and see if it works:

```
numeric_cols = X_train.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[numeric_cols])
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test[numeric_cols])
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens beacause,your dataset may contains some of the column as `object type`, as python by default allocated memory in heap. So check the datatypes of column in dataframe by `dataset_Name.dtypes` and make sure to typecast it into `float64`.